# How to recover Mail, Calendar and Contact after Mavericks to Mountain Lion downgrade?

Tags: macos, downgrade

I want to downgrade from Mavericks to ML. If I do this, how can I recover my emails, calendar and contacts after the downgrade?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it being possible. I would most certainly run a trial install on a new drive & experiment, before committing finally to the downgrade.

Comment: To give a more definitive answer we would need to know your email provider and how you access that provider (IMAP or POP3), and whether you sync your contacts or calendar(s) with any provider (such as iCloud or Gmail).

Answer (score 1):

Mail isn't stored on your Mac but on a server of your provider and will backup automatically after sining in again in Mail-App on ML

Export all your contacts by selecting all -> file -> export -> vCard
import the vCard on ML in Contacts file -> import

For Calender, you can select single colored event-collections and export them
file -> export-> export

After that copy all files you now made to an USB/external drive and use them again on ML

Usually all these things should also be stored in the cloud, so they won't be lost when downgrading, best check this before downgrading on iCloud.com

Comment: I am not using iCloud. I am using gmail and my emails are stored on my disk.

Comment: Gabnako, emails are indeed kept on your Mac. Whether there is still a copy on the provider's server is a function of what type of server it is - IMAP or POP3 - and what settings are in place. Kem, your emails are stored on disk, but Gmail is an IMAP provider by default. Unless you changed your Gmail settings to use POP3 and delete after downloading, all emails present in Mail.app should still be present in Gmail too. You can check your settings [here](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/fwdandpop). (Specifically look at the POP Download section and the setting for #2 under that.)

Comment: ok, that's a point, but imap is standard. Also with gmail everything should just work as I explained before.

Comment: Pop enabled and Pop Download: delete Gmail's copy. IMAP is enabled. I also notice  that not all emails are deleted! Anyhow, my emails are stored on disk in different mailboxes.

Comment: would it be ok, if you have the mails as pdfs?

Comment: pdf is not an option. What about exporting mails to thunderbird, downgrade and importe email into apple Mail?